# cannot insert multiple commands into a prepared statement

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

This query works for me when I tried in PG admin query tool:

```
UPDATE bankdetails SET bank_details = 'mysore' ,"PAN"= 123,bank_acc = 456,
                       "UAN"=789,tax = 'myy'
WHERE  user_id = 79;
INSERT INTO bankdetails (user_id,bank_details,"PAN",bank_acc,"UAN",tax)
       SELECT 79,'mysore',123,456,789,'myy'
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM bankdetails WHERE user_id=79);
```

Later I implemented in my code like this:

```
db.query('UPDATE bankdetails SET bank_details = $2 ,"PAN"= $3,bank_acc = $4,"UAN"=$5,tax = $6 WHERE user_id = $1; INSERT INTO bankdetails (user_id,bank_details,"PAN",bank_acc,"UAN",tax) SELECT $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM bankdetails WHERE user_id = $1);', [companyuser.rows[0]._id, data.bankDetails.bank_details, data.bankDetails.PAN, data.bankDetails.bank_acc, data.bankDetails.UAN, data.bankDetails.tax],function(err,bank) {

                if (err) return callback(new Error('error'));
})
```

it says:

> cannot insert multiple commands into a prepared statement

Can some one guide me here?

Comment: The error message means that you cannot execute 2 distinct SQL statements at once. You need to split them up into 2 separate `db.query()` calls in your code

Comment: Why don't you use `insert ... on conflict update ...`? It not only is a single statement it is also safe against concurrent transactions and race conditions.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it requires `unique constraints` here `user_id` is not unique.

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ  2 separate  `db.query()` how? can you please brief me? but it should not contains `if` statements.

Comment: But the way you use this, indicates that you should have a unique constraint on that column.

Comment: `user_id` is just a reference not unique

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do that in a single query using a writeable CTE:

```
with updated as (
   UPDATE bankdetails 
       SET bank_details = 'mysore',
           "PAN"= 123,
            bank_acc = 456,
            "UAN" = 789,
            tax = 'myy'  
  WHERE bankdetails.user_id = 79
  returning *
)
INSERT INTO bankdetails (user_id,bank_details,"PAN",bank_acc,"UAN",tax)
SELECT 79,'mysore',123,456,789,'myy'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM updated);
```

The `insert` will only be executed if the `update` did not change a row.

---

You can even avoid writing the values twice:

```
with data (user_id, bank_details, pan, bank_acc, uan, tax) as (
  values (79, 'mysore', 123, 456, 789, 'myy')
), updated as (
   UPDATE bankdetails 
       SET bank_details = d.bank_details,
           "PAN"= d.pan,
            bank_acc = d.bank_acc,
            "UAN" = d.uan,
            tax = d.tax  
  FROM data d 
  WHERE user_id = d.user_id
  returning *
)
INSERT INTO bankdetails (user_id,bank_details,"PAN",bank_acc,"UAN",tax)
SELECT user_id, bank_details, pan, bank_acc, uan, tax
FROM data
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM updated);
```

I don't know which programming language you are using, but for e.g. a JDBC PreparedStatement you can replace the data in the `values(..)` part with parameter placeholder:

```
with data (user_id, bank_details, pan, bank_acc, uan, tax) as (
  values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
)
...
```

Comment: am using nodejs

Comment: Reading between the lines here, I suspect that @Schüler expects combining queries into a single statement to make them take effect atomically, avoiding race conditions. That's definitely not the case. Your query will produce wrong results and/or raise an ERROR if multiple copies run at the same time. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/17267417/398670

Comment: @CraigRinger: so will the two statements, right?